# In my Android Studio SDK Manager Tools there is no NDK, LLDB, CMake

Tags: android-studio, android-ndk

I follow this [Install and configure NDK document](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/install-ndk):

In this step,

[image]

I found in my Android Studio there is no NDK, LLDB, CMake and so on:

[image]

---

**EDIT-01**

I found many disable sites in my `SDK Updates Sites`:

[image]

Comment: What's in your "SDK Update Sites" tab?

Comment: there are many disable sites under the `SDK Update Sites`, see my edit-01.

Answer (score 0):

The Android update site is either disabled or has an error (not sure exactly what that icon means; if you mouse over it there might be a tooltip). You need to fix that. You can't download things from the repository if all of your repositories are disabled.